# Return row nubber of last number in range that is greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
=LOOKUP(9.999999999999E+307,IF(AB4:AB997>0,AB4:AB997,IF(AB4:AB997="",AQ5,AB4:AB997)))
```

Out of a range of values, the above formula finds the last value, which is greater than 0.
If it is blank in the range then it is equal to whatever is in `AQ5`.

From this, I need to find the row number of this value within the range (Not the sheet)

E.g values in the column are: 11,222,33,44,555

555 is the largest, I need to return the row number of `5` even if this data is in rows 200,350,400,444,1000

What do I need to add for this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to return row number? Your example seems to imply that what you expect is the column number.

Comment: Yes, if there is a better way altogether to return the row number of the last value (that isn't 0) in a range that is welcome to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the **row number** of the last value in the range *C5:C99* that is not **0** *(or blank)*:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(C5:C99))*(C5:C99<>0)))
```

This assumes that there is nothing below **C99**.

[image]

*Once you have the row number, the contents can be retrieved with INDEX()*

**EDIT#1:**

To get the *relative* row number:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX((ROW(C5:C99))*(C5:C99<>0)))-ROW(C5:C99)+1
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it so that the return isn't the row number from the entire sheet, just the row number out of the range? So in your example the output would be 8

Comment: @Aurelius  See **EDIT#1**

Comment: Now you're confusing me Aurelius. Would you want Gary's example to return 8, or 5? In your OP, you say that it should be the rank in the qualifying cells. Now you say, it should be the rank in the cell range...

Comment: That is the one, thanks Gary's Student! Marco, in the OP I sais I wanted to find the `row number of this value within the range (Not the sheet)` 57 is the last number (That isn't 0) in his range and it is 8 rows into the range of `C5:C99`. Hope this is clearer.

Comment: @Aurelius  **REMEMBER**, put nothing below **C99**